# Solving memory leaks using free

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I am trying to eliminate memory leaks in my following program

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
   node_ref head = NULL;
   for (int argi = 0; argi < 5; ++argi) {
      node_ref node = malloc (sizeof (struct node));
      assert (node != NULL);
      node->word = argv[argi];
      node->link = head;
      head = node;
   }
   for (node_ref curr = head; curr->link != NULL; curr = curr->link) {
      printf ("%p->node {word=%p->[%s], link=%p}\n",
              curr, curr->word, curr->word, curr->link);
   }
   while(head != NULL){
   struct node* temp;
   temp = head;
   head++;
   free(temp);
   }
   return 9;
}
```

Yet when I run valgrind it goes crazy with memory leaks, any idea here on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating memory inside the loop which is resulting in multiple memory areas.  It looks like you should be calling malloc() before your loop instead.

EDIT:

After looking at this again, I think the second loop that frees the memory is incorrect.  You are incrementing with `head++;` rather than setting `head = temp->link;`  It is incorrect to assume that `malloc` will give you contiguous memory segments.

Comment: I agree. You should run your free(temp) outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your `free` loop, you use `head++` which will give you garbage.  You want `head = head->link`

Comment: You are correct.  I just put the same thing in my answer at the same time.  I did not mean to duplicate your answer...great minds think alike!